# Textbooks on transcendence theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, continued-fractions, transcendence-theory

Is there a nice, modern textbook (some lecture notes or survey would do, too) that covers the main results and methods from transcendence theory? Ideally, it should also have some good exercises.

So far I have been working mainly with the ($p$-adic) [Subspace Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_theorem) and I played a bit with linear forms in logarithms (in particular with [Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem)).

I am especially interested in the uses of continued fraction methods in transcendence proofs and in results related to [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture). A quick survey of other open problems in transcendence theory would be a great bonus.

Comment: http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/neverending-fractions-introduction-continued-fractions